# Open Google Drive Link Locally in Finder (not corresponding app) on macOS

Tags: macos, finder, google

I can copy a link from the Google Drive finder extension and paste in a document (notes for example), but when I click this link it opens in the browser.

How can I make a link which opens directly in the Google Drive Finder extension if it is installed, and in the browser if not?

Comment: Do you expect the links to still work on computers where the extension is not installed, or do you just want to link to the local file?

Comment: I want it to work like on iOS. When you click a link you get directed to the Drive app and not the browser. I want that on Mac too.

Comment: And if somebody else opens the document and clicks on the link (somebody who hasn't installed Google Drive), what should happen then?

Comment: Exactly the same as on iOS. If he has Google drive app installed : open in app. If not : open in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source tool we created that does what you are asking for: https://github.com/pch-innovations/gdrive-finder-service

It will not open your browser when it is not installed but it can generate shareable links that will be opened in your Finder.

It was especially useful for us in the con text of a Google Workspace to be able to share file links with our colleagues that have access to the same files.